# Word order involving a "cup of coffee"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, style, parenthesis

1) Joan joins Tim at the table with a cup of coffee.

2) Joan joins Tim at the table, with a cup of coffee.

3) Joan, carrying a cup of coffee, joins Tim at the table.

4) Joan joins Tim at the table, carrying a cup of coffee.

5) Carrying a cup of coffee, Joan joins Tim at the table.

How can I write this as simple and natural as possible and so that it's clear that it's Joan's cup of coffee?

Comment: You could say '...with her cup of coffee'.

Comment: I'll just add that Tim doesn't have a cup of coffee.

Answer (score -1):

"1) Joan joins Tim at the table with a cup of coffee." suggests the table has a cup of coffee and both Joan and Tim go to that table.

"2) Joan joins Tim at the table, with a cup of coffee." This says what you want, but it can be misunderstood to mean the same as (1).

"3) Joan, carrying a cup of coffee, joins Tim at the table." Precise and clear.

"4) Joan joins Tim at the table, carrying a cup of coffee." There is a small chance of misunderstanding. Is it the table or Joan that carries the cup? However I would not use "carry" to mean a cup upon a table. So this says what you want.

"5) Carrying a cup of coffee, Joan joins Tim at the table." Precise.

Which is best? Either (3) or (5). Second best would be (4).

Comment: I disagree that a reader would assume 1) "with a cup of coffee" that the table already has a cup of coffee on it. Coffees can be placed on a table but it's always done by someone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Please note that I wrote "suggests". Note also the comma differentiating 1 and 2. But you are partially correct, there is ambiguity in much written text and that is why solicitors (lawyers) are generally much richer than me.